# Javascript default array/object parameter value

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm making up a way of setting function array parameter to a default value (one ES5 not new ES6/2015).

My first idea was this:

```
window.fnc = function(args){
    defaults = {
        height: 120,
        width: 32
    }

    args = args || defaults;

    console.log(args['height']+'x'+args['width'])

}
```

and will be used like this:

```
fnc({height:45, width:12}); //Result: 45x12
```

or

```
fnc(); //Result: 120x32
```

This works ok. But of course at line #7 the args is replaced by defaults or it is not, so if either one of the 2 values are missing i get an `undefined`.

```
fnc({height:45}); //Result: 45xundefined
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this code snippet from time to time:

```
 args = args || defaults;
     for (var opt in defaults) {
        if (defaults.hasOwnProperty(opt) && !args.hasOwnProperty(opt)) {
            args[opt] = defaults[opt];
        }
    }
```

Basically you iterate over all the values from the default arguments (`for (var opt...`) and check against the values of the arguments whether it is missing or not. (`if (defaults.has...`). If it is missing, add the default value (`args[opt] =...`).

*(I think I even found this snippet on SA, but not sure. Will add a link to the original answer if so.)*

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate the keys of default to copy the one missing in args.

```
window.fnc = function(args){
    defaults = {
        height: 120,
        width: 32
    }

    //args = args || defaults;
    if(args == null)
      args = defaults;
    else {
      for(var i in defaults) {
        if(args[i] == null) args[i] = defaults[i];
      }
    }

    console.log(args['height']+'x'+args['width'])

}
```

If you have sub-objects in `defaults`, you will need to do a recursive function.

EDIT:

Recursive example:

```
// check if obj is an object
function isObject(obj) {
  return typeof obj == "object";
}
// check if obj is an array
function isArray(obj) {
  return (typeof obj == "object") && (Object.getPrototypeOf( obj ) === Array.prototype);
}
// copy the attributes from original into dest
function copy_attributes(original, dest) {

  for(var i in original) {

    if(isArray(original[i])) {

      dest[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original[i])); // copy
    }
    else if(isObject(original[i])) {

      copy_attributes(original[i], dest[i]);
    }
    else {

      dest[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original[i])); // copy
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Ok, what do you mean with the recursive? any example?

Comment: `args = args || defaults;` sets `args` to `args` if `args` is not false, else it sets `args` to `defaults`.

Comment: @Mr.Web: the function copy_attributes should help if your defaults variable contains sub-elements.